# 7 True or False Questions: predicate logic - are my answers & proofs correct?

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

This is an abstract from a past exam paper at my university:

[image]

*Below are my answers and reasoning. If you could tell me if my answers are incorrect or my reasoning is not rigorous enough, that would be helpful.*

(i) **False.** A counterexample which disproves the proposition: $\neg p_{1}$, $p_{2}$ does not satisfy  $p_{1}$ $\wedge$ $p_{2}$.

(ii) **False.** $(\neg q \rightarrow\neg p)$ $\iff$ $(p \rightarrow q)$, $(p \rightarrow q)$ $\not\iff$ $\neg (p \rightarrow q)$

(iii) **True.** The formula of any tautology will be such that any truth values assigned to its containing propositional atoms will always result in the compound proposition (in this case, *'the tautology'*) being true.

(iv) **True.** No truth values assigned to the formula's propositional atoms can output True. Thus this is a contradiction. *Note that I used truth table to decide this, but will not iterate it here*.

(v) **True.** If $x$ $<$ $y$, then $\exists j \in \mathbb{Z}$ : $x$ $<$ $\displaystyle\frac{(y-x)}{j}$ + $x$ $<$ $y$. $\space$ $\displaystyle\frac{(y-x)}{j}$ $\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Hence, $\exists z \in \mathbb{Q} (x < z < y)$.

(vi) **False.** There exists no integer larger than all integers.

*Proof by Contradiction:* Assume $\exists x \in \mathbb{Z} : \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, x > y$. Then $\nexists z$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ $: z > x$.

But $\exists z \in \mathbb{Z} : z = x + 1$.

This is because $1$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ and the set $\mathbb{Z}$ is *closed under addition.*

Hence, $\exists z \in \mathbb{Z}$ $: z > x$ $\wedge$ $\nexists z$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ $: z > x$.

Hence, assuming $\exists x \in \mathbb{Z} : \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, x > y$ leads us to a contradiction, thus $\exists x \in \mathbb{Z} : \forall y \in \mathbb{Z}, x > y$  is **False.**

(vii) **True.**

*Direct Proof:* Take any integer $y + 1$.

Thus, $\exists x \in \mathbb{Z} : x > y.$

*Was this all OK?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(iii) is false. The only thing a tautology implies is another tautology! What *is* true is that any proposition implies a tautology, but that is not what the claim says.

Otherwise all your answers are correct, and you have good explanations for them!